# Gradle Multiproject build dependencies: package does not exist

Tags: build, dependencies, gradle, multi-project

My project structure

```
Main_Project/  
--build.gradle  
--settings.gradle  
--com.project.core/  
----build.gradle  
--com.project.core.test/  
----build.gradle <--this requires classes defined in ProjectCore
```

Dependencies for ProjectTest build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':com.project.core')
    testCompile "junit:junit:4"
    runtime files('C:/eclipse/plugins/org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar')
}
```

Here is my settings.gradle:

```
include 'com.project.core',
    'com.project.core.test'
```

Reported error message:

H:\gitwork\com.project.core.test\src\com\project\common\providable\sortedprovidablemanagertest\SimpleObject.java:8: error:
 package com.project.core.providable.abstractions does not exist
import com.project.core.providable.abstractions.AProvidable;

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the project structure.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser, sorry about that. It should be more easily readable now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use project names that differ from the corresponding directory names, you'll have to configure the latter separately:

```
include 'com.project.core'
include 'com.project.core.test'

project(':com.project.core').projectDir = 'ProjectCore'
project(':com.project.core.test').projectDir = 'ProjectTest'
```

Comment: In my haste I did not name the projects correctly. Can you please have a second look?

Comment: Without more information (e.g. reproducible example), it's impossible to say what's wrong. One thing I'd try is not to have dots in project and directory names, but there are lots of other potential causes (misspellings etc.)

Comment: Thanks I'll keep looking. Unfortunately this is a pre-existing project and I am unable to modify project names or layout. The project is much larger than my small example.